# Date format import to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jodatime

I'm trying to set the mapping for the following date to import correctly into elasticsearch, but not having any luck, would someone be able to help point me in the right direction.

----Attempted mapping(s)

```
 "date" : {
                        "type" : "date",
                        "format": "MMM d','yyyy H':'m':'s a",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    },
```

---

```
"format": "MMM dd','yyyy HH':'mm':'ss a",
```

---- Timestamp from log

```
   "date": "Oct 2, 2016 10:03:59 PM",
```

Error I get:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse [date]')
```

Edit: It was a spacing issue between day and year eg. `dd','yyyy`

Comment: What doesn't work? Post your error!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it. I edited and updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a white space:

```
"format": "MMM d',' yyyy H':'m':'s a"
```

Comment: I had just come back to say I figured that out. I appreciate your response, thank you.